# Ajax Call Returns HTML page as response instead of rendering page (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax, render

Hey having a issue with the rendering of a .erb file, in my AJAX call I make a call to my create action on rails where I validate and process the form data and sent back the completed order data as render: json which works fine.

I have a conditional that checks to see if parameter exists, it if does then the completed order data is passed back as a response via render: json

It if doesn't exists it will render a receipt page.

The problem is when I render the receipt page, the full HTML receipt page comes back as a response instead of rendering the page. Please Help!

```
$scope.placeOrder = function() {
        var body = composeOrderBody();
        var isValid = validateForm(body.order);

        if(isValid) {
          var orderComplete = '<%= @orderComplete %>';
          var baseUrl = '<%= request.base_url %>';

          console.log('Passing order object: ', body.order);


          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              },
              url: checkout_url,
              data: {
                order: body.order,
                xhr_request: true
              },
            }).then((function(_this) {
              return function(response) {

              if(typeof response.data == 'undefined' || response.data == null || !response.data) {
                 console.log('Error: missing Order Number from Order Confirmation data.', response.data);
              }

              console.log('Order Confirmation response data object:' , response.data);

              if(orderComplete) {
                var redirectUrl = 'http://' + orderComplete
                var order_params = `?oid=${response.data.oid}?cart=${response.data.cart}?total=${response.data.total}`
                window.location.href = redirectUrl + order_params;
              } else {
                console.log('Base Url: ', baseUrl);

                // window.location.href = `${baseUrl}/receipt`;

              }

              };
            })(this));


        } else {
          console.log('Form Validation or Stripe Validation Failed');
        }

    } // end placeOrder
```

Rails Code

```
# Redirect to orderComplete URL if it's set
  if !@orderComplete.blank?
      puts 'orderComplete parameter is not blank'
    # Sum up all the line item quantities
    qty = @order.line_items.inject(0) {|sum, line_item| sum + line_item.quantity}

    # Get all of the coupons (and values) into a string
    coupons = @order.applied_coupons.map { |coupon| coupon.coupon }.join(',')
    coupon_values = @order.applied_coupons.map { |coupon| '%.2f' % coupon.applied_value.to_f }.join(',')

    order_params = {
      "oid" => URI::escape(@order.number),
      "cart" => URI::escape(@cart),
      "total" => URI::escape('%.2f' % @order.total),
    }

    @redirectUrl = URI.parse(URI.escape(@orderComplete))
    @redirectUrl.query = [@redirectUrl.query, order_params.to_query].compact.join('&')
    @redirectUrl = @redirectUrl.to_s

    if params[:xhr_request]

     render json: order_params.to_json

     return

    end

    render 'receipt_redirect', :layout => 'receipt_redirect'
  else
      puts 'OrderComplete Parameter is blank'

     render 'receipt', :layout => 'receipt', :campaign => @campaign
  end
```

Comment: What do you mean, "instead of rendering the page"? If you expect the rendered HTML to be inserted into the DOM, then you'll have to do that yourself in your JS.

Comment: I think that's my disconnect here, I thought that since I was inside the rails controller it would render my receipt.html.erb file.

Comment: It *is* rendering the receipt. And then sending it back as a response to your JS request. Then you have to *do something* with the returned HTML. Like, insert it into your page. When you say you expect it to be 'rendered', I think you mean you expect the page to change. But, you're making a AJAX call, so the page isn't going to change unless you change it.

Comment: That makes sense thank you.